# remove audio from all mkv files in a directory with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, batch-file

I have a directory full of videos in mkv format, and I want to remove the audio from all of them. I'm using ffmpeg

I tried this command:

```
for f in (*.mkv); do ffmpeg -i "$f" -an -c:v copy "${f%.*}-na.mkv"
```

But  it showing error  f was unexpected at this time.

I tried this command also :

```
for f in *mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -an -c:v copy "${f/%.mkv/-v.mkv}"; done
```

nothing works

Comment: "Nothing works" is generally not helpul for those who want to help. When a command you tried failed, please post the output of the command (including the error message). That said: in your first command there should be no parenthesis around `*.mkv`, and `done`is missing at the end. Then I can see no reason why it should fail.

Comment: Just to be sure: you put the tag `batch-file` (which is dedicated yo Windows scripts) but the syntax of your commands is rather from bash: can you confirm what kind of shell you are using?

Answer (score 0):

On windows with a batch file, you can write something like that :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Remove Audio from all mkv files in a directory with ffmpeg
Set No_Audio_Folder=%~dp0No_Audio_Folder
MkDir "%No_Audio_Folder%">nul 2>&1
@for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%%~na.mkv" -an -c:v copy -y "%No_Audio_Folder%\%%~na_No_Audio.mkv"
Explorer "%No_Audio_Folder%"
```